# MongoLab TTL BSON date object is not recognized

Tags: mlab

When inserting a document to the collection via the shell:

```
db.collection.insert({"createdAt": new Date()})
```

It creates a document that looks like:

```
{
    "_id": { "$oid": xxxxxxxxxxxxxx }
    "createdAt": { "$date": xxxx-xx-xxTxx:xx:xx.xxxZ }
}
```

The index is executed and the document is successfully deleted when it is expired (after 10 seconds for now). Though when creating a document via a restful api call, mongolab does not seem to recognize the key value pair as a BSON date type and it is not deleted. The document that is created via HTTP POST in Java is identical to the one shown above. Though when I edit the document through the mongolab website(not making any changes) and press save, it is processed as a BSON date type and then deleted as expected when the TTL is applied. I'm assuming it is because when I make the POST the body is serialized as a JSON and then the document is created as a JSON. Though if the document looks like a BSON and smells like a BSON, why doesn't mongolab treat it like a BSON until mongolab touches it by itself?

Comment: Sound like it might be a bug. Write us at support@mongolab.com and we'd be happy to help track it down.

Answer (score 1):

Did you solve the issue? I was having exactly the same problem. But I was calling the REST API from JavaScript.

But when I saw format of your object I noticed that the "$date" part is missing in my documents. I used format for JSON objects like this:

```
var doc =
{
  createdAt: new Date()
}
```

Then I changed it to this:

```
var doc =
  {
    createdAt: {
      $date: new Date()
    }
  }
```

And TTL index works now and deletes expired documents. So check the format of the documents you create over the REST API.